# Checking python version through ansible results into error

Tags: ansible

Hi i am checking the version of python using ansible task However i am getting output value in stderr variable instead of stdout.

Here is my ansible task to check pthon version.

```
---
- shell: "python --version"
  register: python_installed
```

Here is the output of the task:

```
changed: [172.17.0.3] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "python --version",
    "delta": "0:00:00.259578",
    "end": "2017-06-30 03:43:44.341772",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "python --version",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2017-06-30 03:43:44.082194",
    "stderr": "Python 2.6.6",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Python 2.6.6"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

I tried to add python path in executable arguement, it also failed.
I also tried using command module insted of shell module. Still failing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no error here. Command has been executed successfully (`rc=0`).

Python's `-v` switch is supposed to write version number to stderr. From [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/828488393ca79f2ceb0acc2d7c30fb68baad85f8/Modules/main.c#L451):

```
fprintf(stderr, "Python %s\n", PY_VERSION);
```

If (for some specific reason) you need to see it in stdout instead, use descriptor redirection:

```
- shell: python --version 2>&1
```

Comment: Note that python 3 has changed behaviour from python 2.  Python 3 outputs version info to stdout (python 2 outputs to stderr, as pointed out in the answer).

Answer (score 14):

Just as a note:

Python version is already gathered by the [setup_module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/setup_module.html) and can be accessed by `ansible_python_version`

> ```
> ansible -m setup localhost | grep ansible_python_version
>        "ansible_python_version": "3.6.1",
> ```